# Database model for multiple user types

Tags: database, postgresql, data-modeling, datamodel

I am working on a project that is very similar to Fiverr (https://www.fiverr.com/). Users who are Service Providers can post jobs, and users who are Service Seekers can hire those providers to complete that job (e.g. Web Development), and it's important to note that users can be both Providers *and* Seekers if applicable.

I'm wondering what an efficient way to model the user data would be for this situation. I am thinking of having a `Users` table, as well as a `ServiceProviders` table, and use the `user_id` as a foreign key in the `ServiceProviders` table, allowing me to store additional data on about the Provider that normal users don't have. Then, I would only create an entry in the ServiceProviders table if the user chooses to "Become a Service Provider".

Do I seem to be on the right track here?

Also, for the `Jobs/Gigs` table, would it be better to use the `user_id` or the `service_provider_id` as the foreign key? I'm not sure as the ServiceProviders table already has the `user_id` as the foreign key.

I'd appreciate any and all feedback on this!

Much appreciated.

Comment: This seems like a good plan, not sure what the question is. Is being a ServiceProvider a requirement of interacting with Jobs/Gigs tables? If not, then use user_id.

Comment: @psychopg2 Thank you for the reply. I guess I am just seeking general feedback but yes I should have asked a more specific question. Yes, being a ServiceProvider user is a requirement to create a Gig, so should I use the service_provider_id in that case?